# WebGrid Replace function in string null reference exception

Tags: string, replace, nullreferenceexception, webmatrix, webgrid

I keep getting

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:


Line 54:                        string review = item.Review;
Line 55:                        //review = review.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>");
Line 56:                        return review.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>");
Line 57:                     }),
Line 58:                     grid.Column(format: @<a href="~/DeleteMovie?id=@item.ID">Delete</a>)
```

.......................  Line: 56

When I try to use the Replace function for the string review. I create and set the instance of review on line 54 and it will output the text I am expecting. But when I try to do a replace I get this error. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 54 does not *create* an instance of `review`, rather it just points to the `item.Review` value that may or may not be null.

Presumably in this case `item.Review` is itself null, and thus `review` is also null.

One thing you could do to work around this is change line 54 to:

```
string review = item.Review ?? "";
```

This will ensure that `review` is never null. It'll either have the contents of `item.Review` or it will be an empty string (which is not null).

Comment: That worked! I'm not quite sure what that extra syntax does but I'll research it later. I'm thinking the ?? is like an or statement. Thank you!

Comment: The syntax is roughly equivalent to: `string review = item.Review == null ? "" : item.Review;` but is shorter. That is, if `item.Review` is null, store `""`, otherwise store the value of `item.Review`.